# How to generate a new string by combine github action workflow variables

Tags: github-actions

I need to generate environment variable from `${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}, ${{ github.sha }}` and here is what I tried so far

```
- name: Setup env var
  run: |
    echo MESSAGE_SHA=${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}-${{ github.sha }}) >> $GITHUB_ENV #only the dash and the SHA is print out 
    echo ${{ env.MESSAGE_SHA }} #Nothing prints out
```

The concatenation for the commit message and commit SHA with the dash is not working at all. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It depends on the event payload; does it have a top-level field `head_commit`? You can dump the event with `jq . "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH"`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried to print out the `github.event.head_commit.message` it is `Merge <SHA1> into <SHA2>` and the echo of the`github.sha`  printed a different SHA with SHA1 and SHA2. More background is I have a PR from feature branch to main, I want to fetch the commit message and the SHA that I pushed to the feature branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3281264723/jobs/5403055070) using this [workflow implementation](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester63.yml).

For what I observed, there are 2 issues in your implementation:

#### First issue

According to the documentation, when [setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable), you can't access the variable **in the same step**.

> You can make an environment variable available to any subsequent steps in a workflow job by defining or updating the environment variable and writing this to the GITHUB_ENV environment file. The step that creates or updates the environment variable does not have access to the new value, but all subsequent steps in a job will have access. The names of environment variables are case-sensitive, and you can include punctuation. For more information, see "[Environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables)."

Therefore, your implementation should instead looks like this:

```
- name: Setup env var
  run: |
    echo MESSAGE_SHA='${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}'-'${{ github.sha }}' >> $GITHUB_ENV

- name: Check env var
  run: |
    echo ${{ env.MESSAGE_SHA }}
```

However, that wouldn't be enough depending the context, due to the second point.

#### Second issue

The `${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}` variable can be a multiline variable, in that case, you would need to create the variable with another syntax before adding it to the `$GITHUB_ENV`.

The solution I came with was using this implementation:

```
      - name: Setup env var
        run: |
          MESSAGE=$(cat << EOF
          '${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}'
          -'${{ github.sha }}'
          EOF
          )
          echo MESSAGE_SHA=$MESSAGE >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

---

Therefore, combining both concepts above, your workflow implementation should look like this to achieve what you want:

```
      - name: Setup env var
        run: |
          MESSAGE=$(cat << EOF
          '${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}'
          -'${{ github.sha }}'
          EOF
          )
          echo MESSAGE_SHA=$MESSAGE >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Check env var
        run: |
          echo ${{ env.MESSAGE_SHA }}
```

*Note that using `echo MESSAGE_SHA='${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}'-'${{ github.sha }}' >> $GITHUB_ENV` could work if you can always guaranty the commit message is a single line.*

**EDIT:**

*This syntax also works to set multilines outputs (and looks easier to use):*

```
      run: |
         echo "TEST=first line \
          second line \
          third line" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```