# How to fix or avoid Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully?

Tags: github-actions

Recently github [has announced change](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/) that `echo "::set-output name=x::y"` command is deprecated and should be replaced by `echo "x=y" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`

The previous command was able to process multilined value of `b` while the new approach fails with the folllowing errors

```
Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.
Error: Invalid format
```

In my script, I populate a variable `message` with a message text that should be sent to slack. I need output variables to pass that text to the next job step which performs the send operation.

```
message="Coverage: $(cat coverage.txt). Covered: $(cat covered.txt). Uncovered: $(cat uncovered.txt). Coverage required: $(cat coverageRequires.csv)"
```

The last part of message includes context of a `csv` file which has multiple lines

While the `set-output` command was able to process such multilined parameters

```
echo "::set-output name=text::$message"
```

the new version fails

```
echo "text=$message" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

What can be done to fix or avoid this error?

Comment: Note: ```Outputs are Unicode strings, and can be a maximum of 1 MB. The total of all outputs in a workflow run can be a maximum of 50 MB.``` --- [Defining outputs for jobs - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs).

Answer (score 36):

The documentation describes [syntax for multiline strings](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings) in a different section but it works even for the output parameters.

**Syntax:**

```
{name}<<{delimiter}
{value}
{delimiter}
```

**This could be interpreted as:**

1. Set output with the defined `name`, and a `delimiter` that would mark the end of the data (typically it would be a plain "EOF" string but it's **strongly** recommended that the delimiter is [random](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings) so the following examples use `EOF` variable set to a random value).
2. Keep reading each line and concatenating it into one input.
3. Once reaching the line consisting of the defined `delimiter`, stop processing. This means that another output could start being added.

Therefore, in your case the following should work and step's `text` output would consist of a multiline string that `$message` contains:

```bash
EOF=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=15 count=1 status=none | base64)
echo "text<<$EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "$message" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "$EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

...and unless you need `$message` for something else, you could actually avoid setting it and get a more readable set of instructions to construct the output:

```bash
EOF=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=15 count=1 status=none | base64)
echo "text<<$EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "Coverage: $(cat coverage.txt)." >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "Covered: $(cat covered.txt)." >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "Uncovered: $(cat uncovered.txt)." >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "Coverage required: $(cat coverageRequires.csv)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "$EOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

**Note:** The last example is not 100% same as yours because it would  contain new lines between the sections. You could use `echo -n` to avoid that.

Comment: Can't use it since my $message variable contains multiple lines

Comment: But handling multilines is the whole point for the syntax I suggested.

Comment: One liner: `echo -e "text<<EOF\n$message\nEOF" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`

Comment: @Preminster, be aware that this will also interpret escape sequences in $message. To avoid that, in bash you can use: `echo "text<<EOF"$'\n'"$message"$'\n'EOF >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`

Comment: You are a lifesaver, I had read that documentation literally 5 times and it still didn't make sense to me. Your clear explanation helped me figure out my own case.

Comment: It took me quite a while to figure out how to reference the output in the next step: `echo "Output [${{steps.my_step.outputs.text}}]"`. Or as minimal code snippet `${{steps.my_step.outputs.text}}`. This did **not** work: `${{steps.my_step.outputs.message}}`. (where `my_step` is the step you did the `... >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` stuff).

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? You said `VAR` in your case is `text` (and not `message`). I think that's pretty much what I wrote :-).

Comment: Thank you @tmt very well explained

Answer (score 7):

> The previous command was able to process multilined value of b while the new approach fails with the folllowing errors

Actually it has not been, but lately they changed the behaviour:

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26288

> What can be done to fix or avoid this error?

The same way as was for the `GITHUB_ENV` variable:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings

```yaml
echo 'var<<EOF' >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "<multi-line-output>" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo 'EOF' >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Or more fancy way:

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26288#discussioncomment-3876281

```yaml
delimiter="$(openssl rand -hex 8)"
echo "output-name<<${delimiter}" >> "${GITHUB_OUTPUT}"
echo "Some\nMultiline\nOutput" >> "${GITHUB_OUTPUT}"
echo "${delimiter}" >> "${GITHUB_OUTPUT}"
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up having replaced all breaklines in the message variables by the command

```
message=$(echo $message | tr '\n' ' ')
echo "text=$message" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

This eliminated the error.

Comment: Note that this isn't useful if the following step, that uses the output variable, needs the newlines to be there. Not a need of mine but to spark your understanding: perhaps its a formatted .md file being created and the output variable holds markdown for a table (which requires newlines in the right places).

Answer (score 1):

```
  steps:
     - run: | 
         some_response=$(curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
           -d "${body}" -X POST "${url}")

         echo response_output=$some_response >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
       id: some-request
     - run: |
         echo "Response is: ${{ steps.some-request.outputs.response_output }}"
```

Worked for me well. Quotes (and curly brackets) are not needed in case of just setting output var

Answer (score 0):

Another option to set multilines in outputs could be using this implementation ([same as for ENV variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings) in the `$GITHUB_ENV`):

```
      - name: Setup output var
        id: test1
        run: |
          MESSAGE=$(cat << EOF
          first line
          second line
          third line
          ...
          EOF
          )
          echo TEST=$MESSAGE >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Check output var
        run: |
          echo ${{steps.test1.outputs.TEST}}
```

I made a test [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3289770106/jobs/5421715880) with the same behavior that for environment variables ([detailed in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74117204/how-to-generate-a-new-string-by-combine-github-action-workflow-variables/74124861#74124861))

---

**EDIT 1:**

*This syntax also works (and looks easier to use):*

```
      run: |
         echo "TEST1=first line \
          second line \
          third line" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

It's also possible to display the output as multilines (and not on a single line as the other examples above). However, the syntax would be different and you would need yo use `echo -e` together with `\n` inside the variable.

**Example:**

```
      - name: Setup output var
        id: test 
        run: echo "TEST=first line\n second line\n third line" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Check output var
        run: |
          echo ${{steps.test.outputs.TEST}} #Will keep the n from the \n
          echo -e "${{steps.test.outputs.TEST}}" #Will break the line from the \n
```

[image]

Comment: well, how this is different from my question? How does it answer my question? I literally use $message variable and it fails in Github Actions CI context

Comment: This answer is just an alternative to the one you shared, without having to use the `| tr '\n' ' '` syntax (converting the output to a single line). This will allow to keep the variable a multiline output value as the new syntax doesn't work the same way as the `::set-output` expression with multiline variables.

Comment: well, this doesn't work

Comment: It worked in the test I shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74137120/how-to-fix-or-avoid-error-unable-to-process-file-command-output-successfully/74140298?noredirect=1#comment130926010_74140298) using [this implementation](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester63.yml) using a multiline commit message. Feel free to share your implementation to check what can be different :)

Comment: For example, I have either a file with content or a variable

I tried to use your approach

x=$(cat commit.json | jq '.commit.message' -r)
          echo "Last commit message: $x"
          MESSAGE=$(cat << EOF
          '$x'
          EOF
          )
           echo "commit=$MESSAGE" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

and it fails with the same error

Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.

So looks like replacing breaklines is the only option

Comment: It may be related to the fact the workflow couldn't access `commit.json` file directly here. If you want to add the whole workflow implementation to your question editing here, I can try reproducing the error and check what can be done to resolve it.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. Your own [test run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3289770106/jobs/5421715880) doesn't seem to output a multiline string in the "Check env var" step and what you describe in your "EDIT" is a single-line string as well.

Comment: If you want to display the output as multiline, it's possible. However the syntax would be different and you would need yo use `echo -e` together with `\n` inside the variable. I edited the answer with an example.

Answer (score -1):

The cleaner solution, when using base64 is to pass `-w 0` to it to stop it wrapping across multiple lines. Eg.

```bash
echo "text=$(cat path/to/file | base64 -w 0)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Comment: well, I don't really use base64 here

Comment: but you can encode and decode. I see your point, guess I got it from an answer..