# Invalid value. Matching delimiter not found

Tags: github-actions

In updating GitHub actions to reflect the [recent announcement](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/) deprecating set-output, I have run into the following error attempting to send multiline output to GITHUB_OUTPUT following the [provided documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter)

> Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.
>
> Error: Invalid value. Matching delimiter not found 'e8e24219e2b73f81'

Below is the example action:

```
name: Action Test
description: test new action output
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name : write
      run : |
        delimiter="$(openssl rand -hex 8)"
        echo "OUT<<${delimiter}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        cat test.json >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        echo "${delimiter}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell : bash
      id: write
    - name: Print Output
      run: echo ${{ steps.write.outputs.OUT }}
      shell: bash
```

In theory this should generate a random delimiter, put it at the beginning and end of the output, and allow the action to then print the multiline file. In practice, I'm unsure what is happening to the second instance of the delimiter as there is no match.

I have tried various solutions such as those posted in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74137120/how-to-fix-or-avoid-error-unable-to-process-file-command-output-successfully/74232400#74232400?newreg=a35547c217d24c03875dfc87094e17a1)

Comment: Could it be that `test.json` is a single line without a linebreak at the end? Try adding `wc -l test.json` to the workflow to see. It that shows `0`, the closing delimiter won't be on the start of a line.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have verified with wc -l that it is 74 lines long

Comment: But does it end with a newline? You can check with `tail -c1 "test.json | wc -l`; if that's `0`, there is no newline, and you would end up with your problem.

Comment: So, interestingly the newline at the end *does* impact whether you can echo the Output. But it will still throw the Matching delimiter error

Comment: Yes, when there is no newline at the end, the closing delimiter isn't at the beginning of a line, and you get the complaint about it. I don't understand why adding the newline doesn't fix it, though.

Comment: I'm not sure. I was unable to solve this problem and avoided it by writing to files instead of using GITHUB_OUTPUT

Answer (score 4):

This turned out not to be the issue at hand for the asker, but would lead to the same error message, so leaving it here:

The JSON file is missing a newline at the end, so the actual contents written to the output file look something like

```
OUT<<eabbd4511f4f29ab
{"key":"value"}eabbd4511f4f29ab
```

and the closing delimiter can't be found because it's not at the beginning of a line.

To fix, we can apply [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31955/118235) to add a newline if it's missing:

```yaml
      run : |
        delimiter=$(openssl rand -hex 8)
        {
            echo "OUT<<$delimiter"
            sed -e '$a\' test.json
            echo "$delimiter"
        } >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
      shell: bash
```

Comment: I had previously marked this as correct, but the first run I did with this update seems to have been a fluke, or perhaps I misremembered the result. Adding a newline to the end of the file produces the same error, although it does allow the action to print the file contents